# In React component without state or refs should I prefer normal functions, but not arrow functions?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

So, when I have component like that:

```
    import React from 'react';
    import VideoListItem from './VideoListItem';

    const VideoList = (props) => {
      const videoItems = props.videos.map((oneElObj) => {
        return (
          <VideoListItem
            handleVideoSelect_1={props.handleVideoSelect_2}
            key={oneElObj.etag}
            clip={oneElObj}
          />
        );
      });
      return (
        <ul className="col-md-4 list-group">
          {videoItems}
        </ul>
      );
    };

    export default VideoList;
```

Should I always refactor it like so?

```
import React from 'react';
import VideoListItem from './VideoListItem';

function VideoList(props) {
  const videoItems = props.videos.map((oneElObj) => {
    return (
      <VideoListItem
        handleVideoSelect_1={props.handleVideoSelect_2}
        key={oneElObj.etag}
        clip={oneElObj}
      />
    );
  });
  return (
    <ul className="col-md-4 list-group">
      {videoItems}
    </ul>
  );
};

export default VideoList;
```

I'm trying to follow that guide [Airbnb React/JSX Style Guide](https://github.com/airbnb/javascript/tree/master/react) and refactor my code like it says but in all tutorials on youtube, they say statless components, should look like this

```
const VideoList = (props) => {
```

What is correct?

Comment: Yes. You should use normal functions. Since there in no context, binding `this` will not do much. It will not cause issues as you are not using it at all.

Comment: Ok, good to know, thanks!

Comment: "Should" you? Meh. It's an opinion.